# Motor Index not created on empty Collection

Tags: mongodb, tornado-motor

I have the following code to setup my database:

```
self.con = motor.MotorClient(host, port)
self.Db = self.con.DB
self.Col = self.Db.Col

self.Col.create_index("c")
self.Col.create_index("h")
```

When I run `index_information()` I only see index information on _id field. However if I move the `create_index()` after some entries are inserted the `index_information()` shows the new indexes. Does this mean I have to wait until I have entries in the collection before I can create indexes? Is there another way to do this since I start with an empty collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* create an index on an empty, or non-existent, MongoDB collection, and the index appears in `index_information`:

```
>>> from tornado import ioloop, gen
>>> import motor
>>>
>>> con = motor.MotorClient()
>>> db = con.test
>>> col = db.collection
>>>
>>>
>>> @gen.coroutine
... def coro():
...     yield db.drop_collection("collection")
...     yield col.create_index("c")
...     yield col.create_index("h")
...     print((yield col.index_information()))
...
>>> ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_sync(coro)
{u'c_1': {u'key': [(u'c', 1)], u'v': 1}, u'_id_': {u'key': [(u'_id', 1)], u'v': 1}, u'h_1': {u'key': [(u'h', 1)], u'v': 1}}
```

Since I don't see any "yield" statements in your example code, or any callbacks, I suspect you're not using Motor correctly. Motor is asynchronous; in order to wait for any Motor method that talks to the database server to complete you must either pass a callback to the method, or yield the Future the method returns.

For more information consult the tutorial:

http://motor.readthedocs.org/en/stable/tutorial.html#inserting-a-document

The discussion of calling asynchronous methods with Motor (and this applies to all Tornado libraries, not just Motor) begins at the "inserting a document" section.

Comment: hi Jesse, thanks for your response. I did yield everything except the create_index() because i perform that inside the constructor. I will see if this makes and difference and write back thanks.

Comment: I just realised I dropped the collection for debugging purposes after I created the index in __init__

Comment: This is a good reason not to do network operations in a constructor! I've found that to be an anti-pattern in general, and basically impossible to do correctly in async code. Best to do no network I/O in the constructor, and instead do it in a function like "open()" on the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily create the index on mongodb (even on empty collection) using
**`field_name`** and **`direction`**.

> **`field_name`:** can be any field on which you want to create the index.
> **`direction`:** can be any one from these values: `1`, `-1`, `2dsphere`, `text` or `hashed`

**[Refer MotorCollection Doc for details](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-tornado/motor_collection.html)**

In the below code I am trying to create index using **`motor`** library and **`python`**.

```py
db.collection_name.create_index([("field_name", 1)] # To create ascending index
db.collection_name.create_index([("geoloc_field_name", "2dsphere")] # To create geo index
db.collection_name.create_index([("field_name", "text")] # To create text based index
```